# How to find possible IP-Subnets from list of IP-Addresses in python

Tags: python-3.x, networking, ip

I have a large list of Public IP-Addresses.
There are a lot of neighbour Addresses in the list, so I want to combine neighbour Addresses to Subnets.

example:

```
- 104.103.72.184/32 
- 92.123.194.10/32  
- 92.123.194.100/32 
- 92.123.194.105/32 
- 92.123.194.106/32 
- 92.123.194.107/32 
- 92.123.194.108/32 
- 92.123.194.109/32
- 92.123.194.110/32
- 92.123.194.112/32 
- 92.123.194.114/32 
- 92.123.194.115/32 
- 92.123.194.118/32
```

The Result should be:

```
- 104.103.72.184/32 
- 92.123.194.10/32  
- 92.123.194.100/32 
- 92.123.194.104/29
- 92.123.194.113/32 
- 92.123.194.114/31  
- 92.123.194.118/32
```

How can I realize this in Python3?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the netaddr module.
Your code could look something like this:

```
import sys
from netaddr import IPAddress, cidr_merge

fh     = open (sys.argv[1], 'r')
iplist = list()
for addr in fh:
    addr = IPAddress (addr.strip())
    iplist.append (addr)

fh.close()
print cidr_merge (iplist)
```

Also you can find more information related on how to
summarize groups of IP subnets and addresses,on this [link](https://netaddr.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial_01.html#summarizing-list-of-addresses-and-subnets)